# Submitting App from building in Xcode 6.4

Tags: objective-c, app-store-connect, ios9, xcode7, xcode6.4

I previously built my app in an Xcode 7 beta as my testing device is an iOS 9.0 device. I recently deleted Xcode 7 and began working on my app in Xcode 6.4 (not a beta). 6.4 does not support iOS 9 but my iPhone on an iOS 9 Beta is not uneligible (as it should because 6.4 doesn't support 9.0). Are there some files I can remove so that my device is ineligible? I believe once I fix this problem, I can finally submit a new build for review to iTunes Connect because I shouldn't get this error message when submitting my app:

> New apps and app updates submitted to the App Store must be built with public (GM) versions of Xcode 6 or higher and iOS 8 SDK. Do not submit apps built with beta software for store review.

Also, my app is not written in Swift so I cannot do the Swift 2.0 conversion to Swift 1.2.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Apps that you submit should be developed using the latest version of Xcode from the Mac App Store and should be built for publicly available versions of iOS, OS X, and watchOS — except when GM seeds are available.
 Now Mac App Store's Xcode is 6.4 and OS X Yosemite is Build 14F27.
 If you user xcode 6.4 on OS X El Capitan, you should follow the steps:

1. Using Xcode, then archive your project
2. Open organizer, find your .xcarchive file
   [image: find .xcarchive file]
3. Right click the xcarchive file, choose [Show package Contents]
4. Find Products/Applications/XXX.app/Info.plist
5. then change [BuildMachineOSBuild] value to 14F27, just like this:
   [image: example]
6. Now, you can go to Xcode->organizer, then 【Submit to App Store】

Comment: Holy sh*t it worked! Thank you What is this 14F27 code?

Comment: 14F27 is a release for Yosemite, You're basically telling the binary that it was built on Yosemite instead of El Cap.

Comment: All right, because el captian now is beta, not the release OS X

Comment: cross your fingers and hope no compatibility issues are there. Usually there are reasons why is Apple saying don't use xcode 6.4 on El Capitan.

Comment: @JurajAntas Any updates on this? Or should i send it with Yosemite? I use Xcode 7 iOS 9

Comment: In case you need to revert this change. El Capitan has a Build ID of '15A279b'

Comment: Did anyone else have to modify the DTSDKBuild, DTPlatformBuild, DTXcodeBuild, or DTXcode values as well?

Comment: It is incredible how things get half cooked for developers. Apple hates us.

Comment: I don't see the info.plist option. Went into the xxx.app and then opened the info.plist there - but I don't see the build machine option

Comment: El Cap is 15B42 for the latest non-beta.

Answer (score 2):

> New apps and app updates submitted to the App Store must be built with public (GM) versions of Xcode 6 or higher and iOS 8 SDK. Do not submit apps built with beta software for store review.

This problem comes when you submit App with Xcode 7 (i.e Beta Version).. Clean your build, increment build number and archive again and submit your app with Xcode 6.4, and this error will go away. Then submit the latest version of the build

Comment: I am submitting my app with Xcode 6.4. As I said above, I unistalled Xcode 7 Beta. I am cleaning and building in Xcode 6.4, submitting my archive through Xcode 6.4. I even went into my archive folder to manually delete all of Xcode 7 built archives. I am still getting the **same** error message.

Comment: Did you delete the build on iTunes too?

Comment: I have not. How can I do that?

Comment: Sorry, you can delete the build manually on itunes but you can submit new build. Change the build number (ie increment) it and upload new build then

Comment: That also does not work. I have submitted about 3 builds using Xcode 6.4 doing different things and nothing has worked.

Comment: @AndrewAnthonyGerst not when building on an El Capitan Beta. For my case, the answer marked as the correct answer, is the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't upload my binary even though I was using Xcode 8.3 public version.

Finally I found the issue , I have mistakenly selected Xcode 3.2-compatible in project format under project document. I changed it to Xcode 8.0-compatible and build & archived it. I could upload it without any errors. Check the screen shot attached ..

Hope this will help some one.

[image]

Comment: MIND BOGGLING TIP