# iOS app submission yields "invalid toolchain" although Xcode is up-to-date

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, app-store-connect

I have submitted my app to the app store using Xcode 6.4 on OS X 10.11, the app was pre-approved for testing. I then iterated through 5 builds all of which were uploaded successfully and installed on multiple test devices. Now that I am trying to submit for the final approval, I am getting:

`"Invalid Toolchain. New apps and app updates must be built with the public (GM) versions of Xcode 6 or later, and iOS 8 SDK or later. Don't submit apps built with beta software.
"`

How can this be given that I am using Xcode 6.4, the app is set to run on iOS 8 or greater, and all of my previous builds, including the current, have been just fine getting into the test program and being installed?

Does anyone know how I could rectify this situation to get my app into the final step?

Comment: What do your Build Settings say for Base SDK?

Comment: @PhillipMills "Latest iOS (iOS 8.4)"

Comment: Did you by any chance run Xcode 7 beta 6? If so, you may want to delete derived data. What does `xcode-select` say?

Comment: @SwiftArchitect 

I did run X7b6 before, but it caused some crashes on X6 and so I deleted both and reinstalled X6 only. Tried a bunch of solutions, but wiping everything clean was the only way to fix it. 

xcode-select says `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer` and 'version 2343`. Am I looking for something specific?

Comment: Also posted this on Apple's developer forum (https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/16237), and based on prior submissions, nobody seems to have a definitive clue.

Comment: I had this same problem. I was building using latest Xcode 6 on an El Cap system. When I took the same project and cleaned the project and rebuilt it on a Yosemite system and submitted: worked first time.

Comment: I started seeing this error on Sept 1, 2016.  XCode 7.3.1.  Did something break?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

OS X 10.11 El Capitan is  a beta software you cannot use it to build and submit iOS App to the store.

There is a dirty way to manage it but I personally would not do it https://stackoverflow.com/a/32233429/3979236

Comment: Thanks dude. Believe it or not, was just about to do something like this before going to bed last night, but was too exhausted. lol! Thank you very much for the answer!

Comment: p.s. It's totally beyond me why an iOS binary would contain information about the OS X system it was built on...

Comment: El Capitan is GM so not beta per se, and should be allowed right? But in fact, it cannot be used??

Comment: @Jonny It was still in beta a the time the question was asked. Should be ok now

Comment: I'm getting the same error with the Xcode 7.0.1 and Yosemite.

Comment: Apple changed something in Xcode 7 s.t you can't just overwrite the version anymore. It uses your signing identity upon compilation, and breaks if you change the file.

Comment: I think they did not, I just successfully did it with Xcode 7.0.1 and OSX 10.11.1beta. The thing was that at first I changed the value using just text editor and then it broke, then I tried opening and modifying this plist in Xcode and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you installed a beta version of a non GM Xcode, your toolchain may be confused.

Go to `Accounts` in Xcode Preferences, select the account name under which you are attempting to publish, and View Details...

In **Signing Identities** > Action, either `Create` the missing one or `Reset` the offending one.

Comment: This is what I see under my signing identities. http://cl.ly/image/0i0J2u1v1v2e

Forgive the stupid question, but I haven't done an ios/mac app in 5 years, and don't remember how all of this works together anymore. How does Xcode get these identities? i.e. on the screenshot you'll see "iOS Distribution" as one, but in my iTunes connect, it doesn't exist :/ Instead, I have one which I created, but with a different name. Further, what's the process to actually `reset` if indeed that's the issue? </noob>

Comment: Not stupid. These identities are driving every developer mad. Go to `Accounts`, and manage first your `Apple IDs` (you probably should have one), and under each Apple ID, the various programs you are part of. Once that is done, go to your project, its target, **Build Settings**, and manage the **Code Signing Identity** to match.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. Tried rebuilding with a new profile... still doesn't work. According to Apple's forum, this could be internal or due to El Capitan interfering somehow, but they haven't posted a solution quite yet either. It's a black box, and everyone's guessing :/

Answer (score 0):

For anyone getting this error while using xcode 7 beta.

I went to the appstore and downloaded xcode 7.0.1 and then re-archived and released and it worked fine on the first try.