# Error While submitting tvOS app

Tags: xcode, tvos

I am getting a error while submitting the tvOS app to app store as i am not getting any error while uploading build on app store. The error is Invalid toolchain error suggesting to use stable GM version of xcode, but i am using stable version for development.
XCODE Version - 7.1

any help is appreciated.[image]

I have attached the image of error below

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS app submission yields "invalid toolchain" although Xcode is up-to-date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32337165/ios-app-submission-yields-invalid-toolchain-although-xcode-is-up-to-date)

Comment: well the xcode version he was using is 6.4 and that's a beta but the xcode which i am using is not beta @PetahChristian